# MySQL Decimal DataType - Truncating Insert Values With Commas?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, mysql-error-1064

I have a MySQL field that is of the type Decimal(12,2). Upon using the following query to get an insert, I'm not getting the correct value stored.

```
INSERT INTO table (someValue) VALUES ('1,200');
```

This, instead of displaying "1200.00" in the decimal field "someValue", is displaying "1.00" - truncating the data after the first comma.

My questions are, why does MySQL have this behavior, and is there a simple way to get around it?

Comment: you should remove the comma on insert. a comma (thousands separator ) is not part of a number

Answer (score 1):

if your value is read from some HTML form and you can't avoid the comma being sent to the query, do as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table (someValue) VALUES (replace('1,200',',','');
```

that should do....